# Attempting to save intermediate states when running rmh yields error

Tags: r, spatstat

I am trying to simulate a multitype point process, saving the intermediate states every 1000 steps in `rmhcontrol`. However, I can't simulate whenever I specify `nsave`. As an example, whenever I run the code block below, I get the error:

```
Error in factor(Cmprop, levels = Ctypes) : object 'Cmprop' not found
```

The code is:

```
library(spatstat)
library(optimbase)
num_marks <- length(unique(marks(amacrine)))
iradii <- .1*ones(nrow=num_marks,ncol=num_marks)
MSH1 <- MultiStraussHard(iradii=iradii)
x <- ppm(amacrine, trend =~polynom(x,y,3), interaction=MSH1)
control <- rmhcontrol(nsave=1e3)
rmh(x,control=control)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which version of spatstat are you using?

Comment: I am using spatstat 1.62-2 and optimbase_1.0-9.

Comment: This is probably a bug associated with recent changes to rmh.default. I will investigate this in 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in `spatstat` versions `1.62-1` and `1.62-2`.

It has already been fixed in the current development version `1.62-2.006` which you can download from [the GitHub repository for spatstat](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat). The next public release on CRAN will be at the end of January 2020.

Please note: the code in the original question generates an error because `ones` has formal arguments `nx, ny` rather than `nrow, ncol`. The following code tests the bug:

```
library(spatstat)
nm <- length(levels(marks(amacrine)))
ir <- matrix(0.1, nm, nm)
MSH1 <- MultiStraussHard(iradii=ir)
fit <- ppm(amacrine ~ polynom(x,y,3), MSH1)
rmh(fit, nsave=1e3, verbose=FALSE)
```